# I can't see my name in close question tag

Tags: discussion, flags

I flag questions that are duplicates, no real questions, not useful, etc. I got **90** helpful flags.

I can't see my name below the question I flag to be closed. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your name does not appear there is that you only flagged the question for closure, and you did not cast actual close vote since you lack the required reputation for that. Such flags are still helpful and recorded, and can give badges, but they're not public information.

Casting actual close votes requires [3K rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh: Earn 3K reputation,and then your close votes will make your name publish there.\